# $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is homeomorphic to which subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set

In an interview the interviewer asked me the following but I failed to give the answer.

$\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ with product topology is homeomorphic to which subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Can anyone give me the answer and explain me please? thanks for your kind help.

Comment: You need to precise what topology you put on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, although I guess it is the product topology of the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: It's un ill-formed question until the topology on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is defined. I'm guessing the product topology or the compact open topology with $\{0,1\}$ having the discrete topology (which I think are the same in this case)?

Comment: It's the cantor set. $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\mapsto\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{3^k}$ is a homeomorphism between the space of sequences into $\{0,2\}$ and the cantor set, provided that the two-element set has the discrete and the product has the product topology.

Comment: OT: Interview? What interview?

Answer (score 8):

I am going to assume that the topology on $\{0,1\}$ is the discrete topology.

The space $\{0,1\}^\Bbb N$ is called the Cantor space. It is a zero-dimensional compact metric space which has no isolated points. From these properties also follow that it is totally disconnected as well.

But there is a nontrivial theorem (by Brouwer, I believe) stating the following:

> Every completely metrizable, totally disconnected compact space without isolated points is homeomorphic to the Cantor space.

Since every subset of $\Bbb R$ is metrizable, and every compact subset is completely metrizable (because compact metric spaces are complete), it follows that $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor space if and only if it is compact, totally disconnected and without isolated points.

---

I just noticed that I read the question wrong, and it asks about a particular subset, rather than a characterization of all the subsets.

In this case the simplest answer would be the set of all real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ that in their base $3$ digit expansion (taking finite expansion over infinite when we can, e.g. $0.2$ over $0.\bar 1$) the digit $1$ does not appear at all.

To see this, note that we can map a sequence $\langle a_n\mid n\in\Bbb n\rangle$ in the product to the real number $\sum_{n=1}^\infty2\frac{a_n}{3^n}$, which is a number in the interval $[0,1]$ that in its trenary expansion there is no digit $1$. It is not hard to show that this is a bijection.

To show that it is a homeomorphism, note that a basic open set in $\{0,1\}^\Bbb N$ is all the sequences which have some finite number of coordinates fixed. This defines some number in $[0,1]$, and we can find some $\varepsilon$ that every sequence in our basic open set is within $\varepsilon$ distance of this number; and vice versa, given a number in the range and some basic open interval around it we can define the basic open set in $\{0,1\}^\Bbb N$ whose image is contained in the interval.

Comment: But there is a straightforward way of seeing that the two spaces in question are isomorphic, without needing to resort to an abstract general result.

Comment: @Andres: There is? I guess I just learned the abstract theorem first, and then I never had to resort to specifics... :-)

Comment: Given a sequence $a_0,a_1,\dots$ in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, we associate a number $x$ in the Cantor set to it. The association is a homeomorphism: If $a_0=0$, $x$ is in $[0,1/3]$, else in $[2/3,1]$. Say $a_0=0$. If $a_1=0$, $x$ is in $[0,1/9]$, else in $[2/9,1/3]$. Etc.

Comment: @Andres: Well, if you want just one particular Cantor set, sure. But I came to understand that the question was to characterize *all* the subsets which are homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^\Bbb N$. For this, I believe, the general theorem is needed.

Comment: Gotcha.${}{}{}$

Comment: @Andres: Now I see, however, that the question was indeed about the particular case. I shall add this to my answer, then. Although I am certain that an answer using the much more general theorem would have been far more impressive. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This idea was dealt with by Roger Penrose in page 370 of his book "*[The Road to Reality: A Complete Guide to the Laws of the Universe](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Road-Reality-Complete-Guide-Universe/dp/0099440687)*".

The set is called the [Cantor Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), and according to Wikipedia: As a topological space, the Cantor set is naturally homeomorphic to the product of countably many copies of the space $\{0, 1\}$, where each copy carries the discrete topology. This is the space of all sequences in two digits.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by the reference to Penrose's book.  I trust you that the Cantor set appears there, but this reference is neither freely accessible nor anything close to primary, so what is your reason for giving it?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark It sprang to mind when I read the OP's post, that's all.